# ¿Cómo crear carpetas ocultas en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Alguno sabe cómo crear carpetas ocultas (Windows) en python?, sé que con el módulo `os`
se pueden crear carpetas, pero no sé como hacer que dichas carpetas creadas se encuentren ocultas para el usuario.

```
import os
os.makedirs(r'C:\ProgramaEjemplo', exist_ok = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
import os
os.makedirs('ProgramaEjemplo', exist_ok = True)
os.system( "attrib +h ProgramaEjemplo" )
```

Esconder archivo '+h'

Mostrar archivo '-h'

Nota: ProgramaEjemplo debe incluir la ruta completa en ambas líneas

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió =D.